# elasticsearch: document TTL < indices.ttl.interval

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following "problem". I have enabled ttl using the index mapping and Im putting documents with a ttl parameter and it works... somewhat:

- documents are expired and removed
- the issue looks like if you set a ttl that is smaller than the indices.ttl.interval parameter it only expires every interval

Is this how its intended to work? I am assuming that even though the docs aren't actually purged yet (which happens every interval) a GET would still return "null" if the TTL has passed.

Am I doing something wrong? I am reluctant to decrease the indices.ttl.interval to the minimum ttl I am planning to use (1-10 seconds) as I assume this will put quit a load on the index

Thanks,

Sander

Answer (score 2):

Right, that's how it is supposed to work. The `indices.ttl.interval` is effectively the wait between consecutive runs of the purger thread. If `_ttl` is lower than that, you see and get the document back till it gets effectively deleted at the following run of the purger.

The way to fix this is to have the purger thread to run more often, which you can achieve by lowering the `indices.ttl.interval` settings. Otherwise, using those low ttl values doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes thats what I figured... Hmmmm, sounds a bit awkward right? ttl can be set to milliseconds (its even the default, if i read the docs right) but I guess its not recommended to run the purger thread that often I suppose? I guess Im using it for something it's not supposed to (cache WS calls to external systems) ;-)

Comment: @SanderSpilleman It seems to me that ES could be updated to check the ttl expiration when reading out results instead of totally ignoring the ttl apart from the purge thread. I would file a feature request with them...

Comment: I would look into lowering the interval, although under a second anyway you would have to wait for the next refresh to happen if you are using search. With get it's a different story as it is real-time. Opening an [issue](http://www.github/com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues) makes sense, at least we can discuss what makes sense to do there, thanks!

Comment: That would be my recommendation as well indeed... and fully purge the docs during the purge run

Comment: what do you mean by fully purge the docs? That is not possible due to lucene internals.

Comment: I mean, keep the purger thread config as it is (so the doc is deleted during the purge run), but just do not return it when you try to GET it by ID (i.e. behave in the same way as if it really was not there)

Comment: that seems doable, but it doesn't mean docs are fully purged ;)